# In PHP would it be fair to say that a Utility classes makes good Singleton Class?

Tags: php, oop, singleton

I am having trouble deciding when to create Singleton Classes
I have one for the Database.

I want to create a class that will be responsible for creating image links. 
I give it the URL, the image, title, alt-tags, size, etc...
It returns image link.

Does it make sense to create a class for this? if so, would this be an example of a candidate for Singleton class?

Comment: Sounds like you just need a method for returning an anchor tag? do you really need a class for that?

Comment: some of the links get very complicated. that is why I am thinking of a kinda like a Utility class. A need a lot more then just an anchor.  But that is besides the point. I am new to to php and oop and programming. What I wanted to know is does it it makes sense to create classes like this. and if so would singleton be appropriate.
If I read about one more Car or Person classes I will go crazy.

Comment: lol yeah with software design you will beat your head against a wall for awhile but eventually it starts making sense

Comment: No it doesn't make sense. Your not creating and returning an object, your returning a string. All you need is a function/method. You say some get complicated but your still only passing the same several bits of information to begin with...

Comment: Also there is not minimum size for a class.  Essentially you want it to encapsulate a concept or domain.

Comment: It starts with a single method but things grow.  I would argue is almost always better to have things cleanly encapsulate within classes.

Comment: oh by the way not sure who down voted you but Singleton vs Single Instance vs Static Class vs Instance Class with static variables has alway been a hotly debated topic.  So it is a reasonable question with no clean answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I will make it in before people break out the pitchforks.

In general a Singleton is rarely the right choice from a software design point of view.  However there have been a few times that one was really needed.  Here is my criteria for using a Singleton:

- Instantiating the class multiple times would be harmful to the application.  An example of this might be a class that needs to maintain a persistent connection to a remote resource.  So if you create a new instance of your class you could be spawning tons of connections which could be harmful.  In this case I was able to implement lockless access to the functionality.  So this was one of the rare cases where a Singleton was the best choice.
- You have some shared state that you want encapsulate in a class.  However the only appropriate case for a Singleton here is if this shared state is readonly.  Sharing configuration data is often done through Singletons for example.

Those are only cases that I have needed to use a Singleton.  It is really easy to code yourself into a corner if you get in the habit of overusing them.

For your example above it wouldn't really be a good case for it.  You could just as easily have a HtmlUtil class that exposes helper methods.  When you need access to the functionality you can instantiate this class use it then throw it away.

Comment: But is it not expensive to instantiate class and then trow it away over and over and over?
On a Page Load I might have 20-30 image buttons, 
Then another issue I have with classes the way I see it. Is that they might need resources provided by other classes?

Comment: I am not an expert in PHP but the overhead of instantiating a class in just about any language is super super small unless that class does some serious heavy actions during construction.   I have never seen instantiation overhead become a performance problem.  Actually the opposite where people forget to release things out of memory (I don't miss C++ )